# Does implicitIwait affect set_page_load_timeout python, selenium, chrome driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I have a scraper where I have:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
```

and

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Does implicit wait affect the driver.get() call? I was wondering if my 10 second implicit wait would not allow my 30 second page load timeout to complete and prematurely discontinue the loading of the page after 10 seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no such connection between `set_page_load_timeout` and `implicitly_wait()` as their intentions are different.

`implicitly_wait` waits for an element where `set_page_load_timeout` has to do with the entire DOM loading/rendering depending on the `pageLoadStrategy`.

Are you facing any issues or this is just for information purpose.